# Windows Service not installing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services

I'm attempting this walk-through:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx

On Step 6 I've had problems using `Installutil` so had to copy it into the `Debug` folder of the windows service `exe`. Now the command line runs but the service does not install and I get the following error message.

Where do I start to find the problem?

[image]

This is the commend line application that I'm using:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Visual Studio Command Prompt to ensure that installutil is in your path.

Make sure you run the aforementioned command as Administrator. The easiest way to do that is to find it in the start menu and then right click it, and choose "Run as Administrator". The quickest way is to press the start button, type "visual studio command prompt" and then press control+shift+enter.

[image: Run as Admin]

Comment: I'm using 2012... but I reckon I've got the correct app. I'll add a screenshot to the OP. will try running as administrator to see if this helps the installation

Comment: if I "Run as administrator" then I can't get out of the C-Drive...the exe that I'm trying to install is on the R-Drive