# How to resolve "'installutil' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, cmd

Just tried to run an application via the following:

[image]

I have browsed to the directory with an app `WindowsService1.exe` in it, then tried the command `Installutil WindowsService1.exe` but got the following error...

[image]

As VS has only been installed for a day or two I'm worried that something may be wrong with that install as it should recognise installutil.

Are there some basic diagnostics I can perform to ensure that VS Command Prompt is finding all the programs that it should ?

**EDIT**

If i run `PATH` in the command prompt I see the following:

[image]

Comment: did you try it running as an administrator?

Comment: You can try to do a repair from the "Add or Remove Programs" window.

Comment: If you type `PATH` from the VS Command Prompt you should see a sizable list of path variables (on my machine, I see about 20 lines worth). If this list is small then there may be something wrong with the install. If installutil is on the machine but not being located, it's a path variable problem. If it's missing altogether, that's a different problem.

Comment: if I open command prompt as administrator how do I install a file that is on the `R:\Drive` i.e if I right click in the Start menu and choose "Run as Administrator" how do I get out of the `C:\Drive`? If I type the command `R:` it doesn't go to the R-drive which is the location of the file I wish to install

Comment: `installutil "r:\path here\"` (quotes important if there are spaces in path)

Comment: @TimMedora ...let me add a screenshot to the OP of what I see when commanding `PATH`..

Comment: Your path appears to be missing `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version`. Not sure what would cause that, but that's where installutil is located and why it's not being found.

Comment: @TimMedora Yep - should have `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` ..What do you suggest? - uninstall VS and re-install it? I wonder if this has anything to do with me installing VB.NET Express before installing VS 2012 ?

Comment: You can find the actual path settings in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat` (on x86)...but I wouldn't suggest modifying that unless you really know what you are doing. You could try repairing the .Net framework first before reinstalling. Beyond that, I don't know what to suggest.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

This is a tiny bit off-topic but I've stopped using InstallUtil to install my services. It's is really easy to just add it to the service itself. Add a reference to `System.Configuration.Install` (not available in the Client Profile editions if I remember right) and then update your Main()-function in Program.cs like this.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    if (Environment.UserInteractive) {
        var parameter = string.Concat(args);
        switch (parameter) {
            case "--install":
                ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                break;
            case "--uninstall":
                ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { "/u", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                break;
        }
    } else {
        ServiceBase[] servicesToRun = { 
            new Service1() 
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
    }
}
```

Then you can just call `WindowsService1.exe` with the `--install` argument and it will install the service and you can forget about `InstallUtil.exe`.

Comment: Catch InvalidOperationException for installation failures and InstallException for uninstallation failures [security and already (un)installed].

Comment: So much better, although I don't get the user interactive part. This is always true when i'm debugging so my service never starts.

Comment: `Environment.UserInteractive` is true when starting the executable directly, ie not via the servicemanager but through the commandline or Visual Studio. You could add a check of `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached` as well to skip that part when debugging in Visual Studio.

Comment: FYI, I've tried this with a service built in VS 2013, and it seems successful based on the output when doing --install, but the service is nowhere to be seen in the Services control panel.

Comment: I've used this in a service built with Visual Studio 2013 and .Net 4.5 and it registered just fine. Does your service register if you use installutil.exe instead?

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren We just uninstalled, and then used installutil and had the same issue... so it was not related to this technique. It turns out the developer that setup our installer left out a lot of the necessary code in the installer constructor that is shown on the example on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.aspx

Comment: today i noticed that 32 bit applications need another installutil than 64 applications. then i found your solution. thanks a lot! (seems to work fine in VS2013, .net 4.5)

Comment: what is `ValidatorService`?

Comment: Thats the name of my service class. This would be `Service1` if you just created a new service project and didn't touch the generated name. I'll update the example so it says `Service1` instead since thats what most will be seeing.

Comment: Love this approach however, using `Environment.UserInteractive` just burned me for 2.5 hours.  We were attempting to install our service via a Powershell script executed from another service (Visual Studio Online Agent).  Seems logical but it took abit to figure out the issue.  We are going to be more explicit and use a `--console` approach to launch the console rather than using `Environment.UserInteractive`.

Comment: Good catch! The whole `UserInteractive` part is just so that you doesn't start the service from commandline if you misspell something, it could easily be skipped and `return;` used instead of `break;`.

Comment: I received 'Error 1053 the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion', when starting service from 'services.msc'.

Comment: Hi! Any idea how to make this service start automatically? I set StartType to Automatic. So it is "Automatic" in services.msc.. But it doesn't unless I manually start it

Comment: Services set to  "Automatic" will start up when Windows starts. If you want to start it directly after registering it you'll need to do it yourself using [ServiceConroller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

Comment: Question Console in admin to install with this method? Can it be used via Project propertiy> debugging > start up parameter?

Comment: Installing requires elevation, but if you start the application without the --install parameter it will run the service as usual.

Comment: As running as administrator was the issue in the original question. not mentionning it in this great answers feelled like it was not a necessity.

Comment: Well no, the original problem was `installutil.exe` not being available in `%PATH%` which is what this is the primary workaround for.

Comment: getting "The name Assembly does not exist in the current context" how to fix that ?!

Comment: You need to add `using System.Reflection;`.

Answer (score 48):

This is what I have done to make it go away:

1. Found where installutil resides on my PC. In my case it was C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
2. Opened a command prompt as an Administrator and changed current directory to above:
   'cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319'
3. Then entered:
   'installutil C:\MyProgramName.exe'

Interestingly, prior to above solution I tried different options, among them adding C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 to the System Path variable, but it still could not find it.

Wish you all smooth installation.

Comment: This answer is the most applicable to the OPs question and the more pragmatic solution of the bunch, imho. At any rate, it worked perfectly for my requirement (which mirrored that of the op).

Answer (score 28):

InstallUtil.exe is typically found under one of the versions listed under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework.

In my case it is under v4.0.30319.

You could just check your path:

echo %PATH%

should give you a list of directories searched for executables.

Comment: VisualStudio command prompt has an installutil command. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd8zc8ha.aspx

Comment: The command prompt in VS is basically a cmd with a different PATH.

Comment: yep - I have `InstallUtil.exe` in the same location as you Daniel i.e `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` and as you can see from the screenshot I've added to the OP this is not a default pathway of command prompt ...what do you suggest to fix this?

Comment: Did you install a Windows SDK after the VS install? I remember seeing problems with the PATH getting broken after such an install. Look for vcvars32.bat in your bin-folder (i.e. under VC/bin folder of your install location).

Comment: Thanks Daniel I forgot the method.

Answer (score 5):

Found a solution on bytes.com

The code to install a service:

```
@ECHO Installing Service...
@SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
@InstallUtil  C:\Unlock_4_Service\bin\Debug\Unlock_4_Service.exe
@ECHO Install Done.
@pause
```

@InstallUtil <.exe file path of your windows service>

Code to uninstall the service

```
@ECHO Installing Service...
@SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
@InstallUtil /u C:\Unlock_4_Service\bin\Debug\Unlock_4_Service.exe
@ECHO Uninstall Done.
@pause
```

@InstallUtil /u <.exe file path of your windows service >

Save the 2 files as service_install.bat and service_uninstall.bat

Run the files as administrator, every time you have to install or uninstall the service.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just add the `installUtil.exe` path in the environment variable to fix this issue.

**Example:**

```
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

Answer (score 4):

Before Installing service using command line...

use 2 steps:

1. cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
2. InstallUtil.exe Path\MyWindowsService.exe

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've modified your path, the following should be available in developer command prompt and not cmd:

- msbuild
- mstest(for ultimate)
- csc
- ilasm

... etc

If those aren't available you may have a corrupted install.

Comment: +1 David - how can I test one of those to see if things are working ok?

Answer (score 2):

This might have occurred because you would not have opened the Command Prompt as an administrator or with Administrative Privileges.

Answer (score 2):

open visual studio command prompt in admin mode i.e., right click on vs command prompt and run as administrator

Answer (score 2):

***According Microsoft [Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-install-and-uninstall-services) :***

> If you’re using the Visual Studio command prompt, `InstallUtil.exe` should be on the system path. If not, you can add it to the path, or use the fully qualified path to invoke it. This tool is installed with the .NET Framework, and its path is :

**<kbd>%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework[64]\</kbd>**

> For example, for the 32-bit version of the .NET Framework 4 or 4.5.*, if your Windows installation directory is C:\Windows, the path is  :

**<kbd>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe</kbd>**

> For the 64-bit version of the .NET Framework 4 or 4.5.*, the default path is :

**<kbd>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe</kbd>**

Comment: and after this, you need to start the service using the command: `net start [Serive Name]` from the command prompt with administrative Privilege.

Answer (score 1):

I got this after I had went back to 2015 from 2017 and I was still using the 2017 command prompt.  Something to check.

Answer (score 1):

```
Add this in windows Environmental variables
First: Right click on My computer or This PC
Second: Click on Environmental Variables
Third: add this path after clicking on path
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat off-topic as it's for use in a C# program, not for command-line use. What we did was locate the InteropServices runtime directory at runtime, eliminating the need to add or use a Path variable. This directly gets the Microsoft.NET Framework utilities folder. Here's a method.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

    public static void InstallService(string serviceExe, bool uninstall = false)
    {
        string installUtilPath = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory() + "InstallUtil.exe";
        Process installProc = new Process();
        installProc.StartInfo.FileName = installUtilPath;
        installProc.StartInfo.Arguments = (uninstall ? " /u " : string.Empty) + @"""" + serviceExe + @"""";
        installProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        installProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        installProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        installProc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        installProc.Start();
        installProc.WaitForExit();
        Debug.WriteLine(installProc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        if (installProc.ExitCode != 0)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Failed to install service: {serviceExe}. Exit code: {installProc.ExitCode}\n Review {serviceExe}.InstallLog for details.\n" +
                $" Utility path: {installUtilPath}.");
        }
    }
```