# Change directory in visual studio command prompt

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I want to know what is the command I should execute in the command window of the visual studio 2013, to change directory to:

`C/:Users/user/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/OutlookAddin/publish/<Most_Recent_Version>/OutlookAddin_TemporaryKey.pfx`

What is the command I must execute?

Comment: `cd` or `chdir`. Type `cd /?` or `help cd` at the command prompt for more info.

Comment: i tried the cd command and i get "cd command is not valid"

Comment: What "command window" are you talking about? The "Visual Studio Command Prompt"? The "Immediate Window" in the IDE itself? Some other window?

Comment: in visual studio if you go to View > Other windows > you find the "Command Window", where i can find VS Command prompt

Comment: In the VS Command Prompt, `cd` or `chdir` works fine, as I mentioned before. I just tested it. I also tested `cd /?` and the help text was displayed, also as I mentioned before.

Comment: okey thanks i was looking in the wrong side thanks at all.

Answer (score 23):

Actually, cd cmd works, but in a bit diff like this:
syntax:

```
cd /d c: or e: etc..
```

where `/d` stands for drive
for instance:

`cd /d C/:Users/user/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/OutlookAddin/publish//OutlookAddin_TemporaryKey.pfx`

No need for the single or double quote in this case.
Now to execute any type of files for instance simply add '.\' before the executed one.

syntax:

`.\OutlookAddin_TemporaryKey.pfx` or `.\example.exe` what so ever

Answer (score 0):

> cd does work. However, keep in mind that if the path you're trying to get to has spaces, you need quotes around it (the path). E.g.:
>
> cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0" Also, note that the
>   "Visual Studio command prompt" that is mentioned in Step 6 is not the
>   "Visual Studio Command Window" - I think this is where the problem
>   comes from. The command prompt is a separate executable that you can
>   start by clicking Start, point to All Programs, point to Microsoft
>   Visual Studio, point to Visual Studio Tools, and then click Visual
>   Studio Command Prompt. Alternatively, just search "Visual Studio" in
>   the search bar in the Start menu, and it should show up

Source: [Using the Command Window in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698343/using-the-command-window-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score -1):

First create a file on CMD (COMMAND PROMPT)
1.cd desktop
2.mkdir filename
3.cd filename
4. code .
(It has to be a space between code and the dot to open up the file in visual studio code)

Note: If you just want to open visual studio, then go to CMD and just type in 'code' without the dot.

Comment: Why did I get a dislike lol?